Pub get gives me error and can't import libraries
First of all, thanks in advance for your time.
I just installed android studio and visual studio code. I followed all steps. PATH included... During the installation all went perfect. But some things are strange.
My gradle options, just appeared once randomly on a android studio reboot. But I have no that icon and options. And not appear jdk menu on settings.
In pubspec.yaml I write new dependency, and when I push pub get button. I get the message 8 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constrains, on pub outdated, it says all at date. Flutter doctor says all ok
I tried all, I googled for 2 days. Tested all, but anything worked for me. I'm really fustrated. Also tried to import them manually, but when I try to import. It says that import it's not recognized like a cmdlet name...
It fails in both vsc and ad.
Tested all. Testing different sdk environement. Adding html:xxx or http:xxx (don't remember), tested flutter or dart upgrade, and all I saw on stackoverflow forum.
Flutter version: 3.22.3 channel stable
Dart version: 3.4.4
Gradle version: 8.9
Android studio version: 2024.1.1 patch 1
Thanks for the help!!

"When I push pub" what is pub? Please edit your question and describe what you mean by "pub".
